# React instantiate a class and populate properties

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a React logging class that I want to use to write messages to AWS Cloud Watch. I need to instantiate it with the config settings (access key, log group, log stream etc) that are held in a DynamoDB table. I'm using a Cognito Access Key to retrieve the config settings via a GetConfigValues function.

I can't call this function in the class constructor (as I would do in .Net) because the state isn't ready (or similar message), so I'm passing the Cognito Access Key into the constructor, then calling a separate function, LoadConfig(), in order to get the config data from DynamoDB.

The function is throwing "Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Logger component." But as far as I can see, I'm already defining a state.

Here's my class (I haven't got round to completing the writeLogMessage function yet)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 
import { createLogStream } from "./../../../node_modules/aws-cloudwatch-log-browser" 
import { GetConfigValues } from "./../../craConfig";
    
    export default class Logger extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                CogAccessKey: props.AccessToken,
                Region: "",
                IAMAccessKey: "",
                IAMSecretKey: "",
                LogGroup: ""
              };
        }
    
        state = {
            LogGroup: "",
            Region: "",
            IAMAccessKey: "",
            IAMSecretKey: "",
            CogAccessKey: ""   
        }
        
        async LoadConfig()
        {
            let config = await GetConfigValues(this.state.CogAccessKey, "SC");
            this.setLogGroup(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "LogGroup" ).ConfigValue);
            this.setRegion("eu-west-2");
            this.setIAMAccessKey(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMAccessToken" ).ConfigValue);
            this.setIAMSecretKey(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMSecretToken" ).ConfigValue);     
        }
    
        setCogAccessKey = (cogAccessKey) =>  { this.setState({CogAccessKey: cogAccessKey }) }
        setLogGroup = (logGroup) =>  { this.setState({LogGroup: logGroup }) }
        setRegion = (region) =>   { this.setState({Region: region }) }
        setIAMAccessKey = (iamAccessKey) => {this.setState({ IAMAccessKey: iamAccessKey  }) }
        setIAMSecretKey = (iamSecretKey) => {this.setState({ IAMSecretKey: iamSecretKey })}
      
        async writeLogMessage(message) {
           
          const config = { 
            logGroupName: this.state.LogGroup, 
            region: this.state.Region, 
            accessKeyId: this.state.AccessKey, 
            secretAccessKey: this.state.SecretKey, 
            local: false        // Optional. If set to true, no LogStream will be created.
          }
    
          createLogStream('your-new-unique-logstream', config)
          .then(data => console.log(`LOG: ${message}`))
          .catch(err => console.log(`Failed to write to log. ERROR: ${message}`))
          // Create a log stream
            // let params = {logGroupName: 'GenesysLogs', logStreamName: this.logStreamName};
            // let logStream = await CloudWatchLogs.createLogStream(params).promise();
            // logStream.then(() => { return;} )
      
            // // Write your message
            // params = {logGroupName: '/Genesys/Recordings', logStreamName: this.logStreamName, logEvents: [ { message: message }]};
            // let logEvent = await CloudWatchLogs.putLogEvents(params).promise();
            // logEvent.then(() => { return;} )
        }   }
```

and this is how I'm using it:

```
const logger = new Logger({AccessToken: user.signInUserSession.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()});
  await logger.LoadConfig();
  await logger.writeLogMessage("Hello");
```

It's clear I'm doing something wrong, I'd stick the instantiation in the ComponentDidMount(), but it's not firing, probably because I'm not actually rendering the class. I'm probably doing this entirely wrong but that's because I'm a .Net developer. Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've got this working by setting the state directly:

```
 this.state = {
        LogGroup: config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "LogGroup" ).ConfigValue,
        Region: "eu-west-2",
        IAMAccessKey: config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMAccessToken" ).ConfigValue,
        IAMSecretKey: config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMSecretToken" ).ConfigValue 
    }
```

rather than through a setState function:

```
this.setLogGroup(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "LogGroup" ).ConfigValue);
    this.setRegion("eu-west-2");
    this.setIAMAccessKey(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMAccessToken" ).ConfigValue);
    this.setIAMSecretKey(config.Items.find(x => x.ConfigKey === "IAMSecretToken" ).ConfigValue);
```

This is not how the tutorials I've read tell you to do it, but it works. I'm probably missing something and it isn't best practice, so any constructive comments you have on the code would be gratefully received!